# ¿es posible saber cuando se elimina un elemento seleccionado en select2 con jquery?

Tags: jquery, select2

Tengo un select2 con varias opciones seleccionadas, la pregunta es, cuando quito uno de esos elementos se puede saber con jquery el evento o como saber que se esta eliminando el elemento?

Comment: el evento `onchange`?, por otro lado que haz intentado, tal cual la pregunta puede ser cerrada por no estar claro lo que se pregunta o demasiado amplia

Comment: pero el evento onchange trae algún metodo que diga que lo que se esta haciendo es seleccioando o eliminando un elemento?

Comment: @JuankGlezz tengo un select2, lo que quiero saber es cuando se selecciona o quita un elemento de la lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en la documentación de `select2` hay un apartado de [programatic control](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic-control) que te muestra como se puede detectar el cambio en las selecciones, las que te interesan son dos `select2:select` y `select2:unselect`, detecta la selección y detecta la deselección  de una opción

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
//creamos el select2
$('select').select2();
//detectamos que opcion se selecciono
$('select').on("select2:select", function (e) { 
  console.log(e.params.data);
});
//detectamos se opcion se quito funciona con select multiple
$('select').on("select2:unselect", function (e) { 
  console.log(e.params.data);
});
```

```css
select{
  width:200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
  <option></option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```